# How do you embed Java into a microcontroller?

Tags: java, c, embed, microcontroller

I have a microcontroller that when an event, I want it to send an email. I know how to use email in Java, but how can I put that Java code in the midst of the C code of the microcontroller?

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
DDRB |= 1 << PINB0; // = 0b00000001
DDRB &= ~(1 << PINB1);
PORTB |= 1 << PINB1;
DDRB |= 1 << PINB2;

while(1)
{
    PORTB ^= 1 << PINB0;
    if(bit_is_clear(PINB, 1)){
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PINB2);
        _delay_ms(100); //SLOW
    }           
    else{
        _delay_ms(10); //FAST
        /////I want the Java code in here/////

        PORTB ^= 1 << PINB2;
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm using an Atmel Atmega8A microcontroller. I'm making a simple alarm system, that if the wire at pin B1 is disconnected, I want to get an email or text notification.

And I'm just a high schooler novice so please don't go over my head too much...

Oh and if someone could water down multithreading in C for me that would be nice. I come from a Java background since that's what they teach in high school.

Comment: What is your microcontroller?

Comment: Just for extra info, if you'd like to be able to run full-on Linux and you aren't tied to specific hardware, check out [Gumstix](https://www.gumstix.com/store/index.php?cPath=33)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well your "question" is to embed Java to your AVR... but what you actually want to is send email. There are some implementations to run Java bytecode (or at least I think so), but I believe *none* of these will be able to send email.

You need to understand that an AVR is very limited in functionality. To send email, your setup will **need to connect to the Internet**, with TCP/IP. Something so complicated that cannot be accomplished with the ATmega8A itself. It *may* be possible to find a hardware which you can communicate via UART in order to send email, or you can simply hook it to a PC and run a application to listen to the COM port and send email, or... anyway **you need extra hardware**.

You may want to look into other microcontrollers instead. I believe there are some with networking support, but they will probably be very expensive. Or, you can just use a Raspberry Pi instead.

Answer (score 1):

Java and C are *very*, *very* different langauges.

You'll need to find a compiler for your microcontroller that supports Java.

However, if your controller can get C compiled via GCC, then use of GCJ may work with certain memory constraints on the target platform. You'll need to generate an object file of the correct architecture, and link it using microcontroller-compatible gcc.

This is ***not worth its time***. I recommend implementing it in C instead.

Besides, opening files and sockets may not occur since a microcontroller usually does not provide **any** kernel routines beyond certain aspects of hardware access. `libc` will also likely be absent or minimal.

You might also not have networking hardware. If you can tell us *which* microcontroller, we could help.

Answer (score 1):

A more direct answer to the question was given already by Alvin Wong, but I feel your question is so out of focus that it might be good to help you refocus it.

You should start understanding what is really happening when you send a mail from a Java program, then understand what part of it can actually be done by your microcontroller, and how.

So, what happens when you run your mail-sending Java program?

1. You wrote the program in the Java language, which got compiled into Java bytecode, which gets interpreted by the Java Virtual Machine, which will call some library provided by the Java runtime,
2. which will (probably indirectly) start a "network communication", which will take advantage of the Operating System network facilities, ...
3. which will use the network hardware,
4. to communicate with a mail server using some mail protocol, and send it some specific sequence of bytes that will make it understand that a mail message is being sent to someone.

The **(1)** part is mediated by all the layers of the Java platform. (Remember: Java is much more than a language).
The **(2)** is a layer (or couple of them) under the Java platform, and includes all of your Operative System (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, whatever).
The **(3)** is a layer comprised of your hardware, and that includes other sublayers like the firmware in your network card, which is still more software that might manage things like the Ethernet / Wifi protocols' details.
The **(4)** layer is rather bits and bytes being flipped on and off in some communication channel (Ethernet, WiFi, whatever).

Now, what part of it can be done with your microcontroller?
A microcontroller sits in the lower part of **(3)**. In your case, the Atmega doesn't even have any network hardware support, so ... I don't know how you are planning to connect to the network. Anyway, even if you had it, you are so close to **(4)** that it would rather be madness to try to go up to **(1)**. **(1)** is say for elephants, **(4)** can be done by ants, and a microcontroller is about the size of a ladybug, to refer to Atmel's mascot :P.

So: stop thinking like an elephant. As it is you will have to work to get to your goal, but if you take the elephant's way, you'll be probably doing a ton of unneeded work - if it can be done at all, which I doubt.

(And if anyway I had to take the elephant's way, namely use Java in an AVR, I would start by looking at GCJ or LLVM options. I know that some work was done to port minimalist JVMs to 8 bit microcontrollers more than a decade ago, but no idea how that evolved)

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, sending an e-mail this way is really really far from your micro (I assume you primarily want to send the mail, not to run a Java VM in there). To get the mail going, you need to connect to the Internet using TCP/IP, then using for example the SMTP protocol, you may be able to accomplish this.

The problematic part is connecting to the Internet. For this you need to get your device on a "suitable wire", which is typically Ethernet, but radio based solutions may also exist. Then you would have to implement everything necessary to communicate on that wire (the whole network stack until TCP/IP). This can not reasonably be done all yourself. One way is to use a micro which has some built in Ethernet connectivity and use for example [lwip](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/) or [Contiki](http://www.contiki-os.org/) depending on your preferences to do the magic. The other way is using extra hardware which does the thing for you such as [this Moxa product](http://www.moxa.com/product/MiiNePort_E1.htm), but you may not be able to implement SMTP over this.

Then you will "only" need to implement a suitable [SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) layer to properly send your mail (one or another of the solutions I presented above may already have this for you).

Answer (score 0):

Your microcontroller will need to support the JDK or Java ME (maybe Sun SPOT).  http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/c.html has an example of using the JNI to start the JVM and invoke your class.

Answer (score 0):

Microcontrollers very very typically are developed in the C environment since in a microcontroller there are limited resources in terms of hardware power. C is used since it allows the most flexibility and allows fine tuning since in the microcontroller environment real-time computer is very essential. That is not to say though, there is java used in the microcontroller world. Very convoluted though, android runs on some java which in the lowest end possible uses a ARM processor (its up to you to decide if you really want to call that a microcontroller). So all in all, yeah I would recommend that you learn C. If you really want to go the java way, I have not personally run into a lot of resources that allows you to use java on a AVR microcontroller. It might be possible, but expect a hit on performance.

If you have no experience in microcontrollers, I would recommend looking into Arduino (arduino.cc).

Best of luck!